# Microsoft Azure > Web App -- SQL Connection was forcibly closed by the remote host -- Happens only for the first call after idle time

Tags: c#, azure, ado.net, connection-pooling

**This is happening on MS Azure application setup while connecting to SQL MI instance.  Traffic flows through the HCM.**

The same code works on-prem setup where web application directly queries SQL server 201.

***"This issue is reproducible if we keep the application idle for a few minutes and retrigger any request which has database interaction". Once the below error is logged, subsequent requests work fine.***

Below Error is logged:

```
    Properties:
      SqlException.Errors = {
        "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. 
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)",
      }
      SqlException.ClientConnectionId = "4560-9ca8-53ea0fdeca60"
      SqlException.Class = "20"
      SqlException.LineNumber = "0"
      SqlException.Number = "10054"
      SqlException.Procedure = ""
      SqlException.Server =""
      SqlException.State = "0"
      SqlException.Source = ".Net SqlClient Data Provider"
      SqlException.ErrorCode = "-2146232060"

    Data:
    HelpLink.ProdName = "Microsoft SQL Server"
    HelpLink.EvtSrc = "MSSQLServer"
    HelpLink.EvtID = "10054"
    HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink"
    HelpLink.LinkId = "20476"
    MS_LoggedBy = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]"

    Stack Trace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
```

**I have tried using documentation available on the internet, MSDN,**

a. I started logging in-detail System.Net logs for HCM. But no issue found at the socket level. Below exception is logged in Event Viewer

```
    HybridConnectionManager Trace: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

b. Considering it may be tcp connection dropping, I tried making connection pool =False.

c. Verified if the connection is being disposed of. Code is written in Using block and disposed has been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this.
This is due to connection drops. We need to use the connection retry mechanism. 
a. Use Enterprise library Transient error blocks
b. Define retry policy
c. Change ado.net connection from SqlConnection to ReliableSqlConnection